# Draw boxes and text on c# MS Charting control

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

i'm using MS Chart control on my WinForms app and having candlestick series with data.
I'm trying to find a way how to draw rectangles/boxes on a specific location (wrapping a couple of candlesticks).

[image: Example chart with boxes]

I tried using annotations but it can't work in my case (it stays same size when zooming in/out).
Also tried with new RangeBar series, but it's not compatible with candlestick series.
There is also problem that all series must have same number of points, else it will throw an exeption.

Any idea how this can be made?

Comment: It should be possible with annotations; just set their AxisX and AxisY and you can locate them with Axis values. Then you could set them from {x1,y1} to {x2,y2}, according to your candlestick data.